# extract characters from filenames and add those as a value in csv python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to extract the first 6 characters in the filenames and add those as a column in a csv file. For example, filename: "CFL200_ABCD (2018-01-01).csv" with content:

```
Date, Time, Age
1/1/2001, 10:00 AM, 30
1/5/2006, 5:00 PM, 25
```

I want to create a new file with content:

```
ID, Date, Time, Count
CFL200, 1/1/2001, 10:00 AM, 30
CFL200, 1/5/2006, 5:00 PM, 25
```

Could anyone please show me how to do this in Python? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `pandas` package

```
import pandas

filename = 'CFL200_ABCD (2018-01-01).csv'

df = pandas.read_csv(filename)
df.insert(0, 'ID', filename[:6])
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: This works but I have a long pathway to the folder containing the file. Is there a way to handle that? Also, how to do this on multiple files. Sorry if I am asking many questions. I am very new so if I should create separate questions, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @Jason Can you give me an example for that?

Comment: for example: "D:/Academic/Post/Sleep/CFL200_ABCD (2018-01-01).csv". I know that I just have to change the index. However, if the file is in another folder, then I have to change the index again.

Comment: You can do something like this `filename.rsplit('/', 1)[-1][:6]`. This will split the string only once and from the right side. Hence you will get the file name.